# Como deixar itens específicos da minha listBox dinâmica inabilitados?

Tags: c#, wpf

Eu tenho uma ListBox que é carregado dinamicamente usando EF. Um dos filtros utilizados é que o produto exista no estoque.

```
var query = (from p in db.Products
                        join s in db.Stocks
                         on new { p.SchoolID, p.ProductID }
                        equals new { s.SchoolID, s.ProductID }
                        where
                            s.Quantity > 0 &&
                            p.Active == true &&
                            p.SchoolID == _idSchool &&
                            p.ProductTypeID == 1
                        select p);
        lst.ItemsSource = query;
```

Cód XAML do meu ListBox...

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Border>
                                <StackPanel Margin="1">
                                    <StackPanel.Background>
                                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="images/btnSalgados.png"/>
                                    </StackPanel.Background>
                                    <TextBlock Margin="0,0,0,0" Padding="4" Width="167" Height="52" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Name}" ToolTip="{Binding Name}" 
                                        TextAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="22" Foreground="White" />
                                    <TextBlock Margin="0,0,0,0"  Padding="4" Width="167" Height="40" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Price, StringFormat=\{0:N\}}" 
                                        TextAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="22" Foreground="White"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

A imagem de como aparece o ListBox para o usuário...

[image: A imagem de como aparece o ListBox para o usuário...]

Eu preciso que se o usuário selecionar um produto que só tem 1 no estoque (pois ao seleciona-ló o estoque do mesmo ficará zerado) esse item seja inabilitado para futuras seleções (para que ele não selecione um produto que não tenha em estoque).

Answer (score 1):

Você necessita de definir um `ValueConverter` que converta a sua quantidade(float) em bool para que possa ser usado com a propriedade IsEnabled(bool).

```
class QuantidadeToBoolConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var quant = (float) value;
        return quant != 0;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

O método `Convert` da classe acima retornará `false` quando a quantidade for zero.

Utilize o Converter adicionando um `ItemContainerStyle`à sua `ListBox`:

```
<ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding quantidade, Converter={StaticResource QuantidadeToBool}}"/>
    </Style>
</ItemContainerStyle>
```

Não esqueça de incluir uma referência ao `Converter`:

```
<converters:QuantidadeToBoolConverter x:Key="QuantidadeToBool"/>
```

Comment: Eu não sei se não der certo porque é uma lista dinâmica ou eu tem algo errado mesmo. No Setter Property se eu colocar o campo Active que existe na tabela Produtos ele fica Enable = false mas quando eu tento usar essa classe de conversão ele não fica Inabilitado.

Comment: Consegui assim...


ListBoxItem item = (ListBoxItem)lst.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(lst.SelectedIndex);
            item.IsEnabled = false;

Comment: Como não tenho acesso ao seu código pouco mais posso acrescentar a não ser que o código que eu postei funciona, pois eu testei e é algo que eu uso com frequência. Claro que o `DataContext` da `ListBox` terá de ter uma propriedade chamada `quantidade` que receba o valor `Quantity` que vem do BD, tal como você tem para `Name`e `Price`

Comment: Sim a parte do XAML funcionou quando eu coloquei um Campo que vem do meu BD Active. Mas quando eu tentei usar o Quantity ele bem acessava a clase QuantidadeToBoolConverter...